# jQuery ajax form submission response not changing on resubmission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Note: this is a jQuery coding exercise and I am not allowed to use plugins or other modules.

I have a jQuery form that gets submitted to a php page. This php page checks if the email is already taken or not. If not an account is created.

I am not going to include the php page to reduce complexity. The main focus is on jQuery.

Note: I am using the skeleton framework

HTML:

```
  <div class="container">
    <form id="myForm" action="validate_signup.php" method="post">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns">
            <h3 class="center">Sign Up</h3>
        </div>
      </div><!--end row-->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="four columns offset-by-four">
          <input class="u-full-width" type="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" name="email">
          <span class="error">Email not entered</span>
        </div>
    </div><!--end row-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="four columns offset-by-four">
          <input class="u-full-width" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="pword" name="pword">
          <span class="error">Password not entered</span>
        </div>
      </div><!--end row-->
      <div class="row">
       <div class="four columns offset-by-four">
          <input class="u-full-width" type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="fname" name="fname">
          <span class="error">First Name not entered</span>
       </div>
    </div><!--end row-->
    <div class="row">
       <div class="four columns offset-by-four">
          <input class="u-full-width" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" id="lname" name="lname">
          <span class="error">Last Name not entered</span>
       </div>
      </div><!--end row-->
      <div class="row">
       <div class="six columns offset-by-four">
          <input class="button-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" name="signup">
       </div>
      </div><!--end row-->
    </form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns">
            <p id="response" class="center no-display"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div><!--end container-->
    <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/signup.js"></script>
```

jQuery:

```
// jQuery form validation
$(document).ready(function(){

    // field mapping
    var form_fields = {
        'email' : 'email',
        'pword' : 'password',
        'fname' : 'first name',
        'lname' : 'last name'
    };

    // ajax data
    var ajaxData = {};

    // make sure form fields were entered
    $('#myForm').on('submit', function() {

        for (var field in form_fields) {
            if (!$('#' + field).val()) {
                $('#' + field).next().addClass('error_show');
            } else if ($('#' + field).val()) {
                $('#' + field).next().removeClass('error_show');
                ajaxData[field] = $('#' + field).val();
            }
        }

        // signup post field to indicate to php submission
        ajaxData['signup'] = 'Submit';

        // send data if it is all there
        if (Object.keys(ajaxData).length === 5) {
            var request = $.ajax({
                url         : 'validate_signup.php',
                method      : 'POST',
                data        : ajaxData,
                dataType    : 'html'
            });

            request.done(function(response) {
                $('#response')
                .append(response)
                .show('slow');
            });

        }

        return false;

    });

});
```

The main HTML line in question where the response gets printed is:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns">
            <p id="response" class="center no-display"></p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Example scenario:

If the user types in an email that is already taken

> Email already in use, please use another.

Gets outputted. If the user modifies the entry and resubmits the form the following gets printed:

> Email already in use, please use another.sign up complete

How can I solve this problem where I remove the old response data with the updated response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/), you are adding more content to the body of the element. Instead, you can call [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to replace the body of the element.

You could change:

```
$('#response').append(response).show('slow');
```

To:

```
$('#response').html(response).show('slow');
```

But I think it would be better to call `.hide()` and [`.empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) just before making the ajax call.

```
$('#response').hide().empty();
```

That way the old response disappears as soon as the submit button is clicked, and it will animate slowly again when the ajax call returns.

Comment: Thanks! In addition to your solution how can I make it so that subsequent resubmissions get printed smoothly with `show('slow')` as the initial request does and the response doesn't just get spitted out.

Comment: If it's not too much to ask for.

Answer (score 0):

Give your error-elements in html an id:

```
    <div class="four columns offset-by-four">
      <input class="u-full-width" type="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" name="email">
      <span class="error">Email not entered</span>
      <span id="requestError"></span>
    </div>
```

with success and error function in the ajax call, you can display the received error:

```
var request = $.ajax({
                url         : 'validate_signup.php',
                method      : 'POST',
                data        : ajaxData,
                dataType    : 'html',
                success     : function(data) {
                     $('#requestError').html(data);
                },
                error       : function() {
                     $('#requestError').html("Error while AJAX");
                }
            });
```

I hope that could help you.